# Saving radio button value using sharedpreferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

First before i continue with this i want to know if i can use these sharedpreferences to do background calculations later on, or will i have to save them to a database to use to show them on other Activities/classes. If i do want to do calculations with numbers entered from this form will i have to change it from string to save to an int?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To save 1 or 2 values, Shared Preferences is better than SQLite.

SharedPreferences are singletons and cached process-wide. so you want to get it loaded as early as possible so you have it in memory before you need it.

Since in your case, it is 1 or 2 values, this should create minimal performance impact.